# Inconsistent byte array read when sent from PC to PC and from PC to Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sockets, jpeg

I have a Server application on my PC which reads a jpg file and sends it through a socket to the android device. The problem is that when android device receives a byte array, it can't be converted to bitmap. I created a PC application to receive that same array and the data received is different than on the android even though I am using the same code to receive it.

Hence my assumption is that I somehow need to read it differently on android.

PC Java Server

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\test1\\test.jpg"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayoutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image,  "jpg", byteArrayoutputStream);
        OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

        byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(byteArrayoutputStream.size()).array();
        outputStream.write(size);
        outputStream.write(byteArrayoutputStream.toByteArray());
        outputStream.flush();

        Thread.sleep((long)5000);
        clientSocket.close();
```

Android receiver

```
    DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream());

    byte[] sizeAr = new byte[4];
    inputStream.read(sizeAr);
    int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();

    byte[] imageAr = new byte[size];
    inputStream.read(imageAr);
    System.out.println(imageAr.toString());
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAr, 0, imageAr.length);//this returns null
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not receiving the whole thing,
Instead:

```
 inputStream.read(imageAr);
```

try:

```
 inputStream.read(imageAr, 0, size);
```

the second form will wait until size bytes are received.

**ADDED**

Also do the same on the first read()

instead: `inputStream.read(sizeAr);` try `inputStream.read(sizeAr, 0, 4);`

Also get and check inputStream.read() return values, it says how many bytes were really read.

Comment: Unfortunately did not help, still got the exact same byte array.